# Entity framework ID order in DB isn't the same everytime?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my Seeder, I do the below, the order of which they land in the DB seems to be different now and then! I need the order to be consistent because I refer to the IDs using static variables stored. Why is the order different? Can I make it consistent? Thank you.

```
    List<BadgeGroup> BGs = new List<BadgeGroup>();
    BadgeGroup Unclassified = new BadgeGroup() { Description = "Unclassified" };
    BGs.Add(Unclassified);

    BadgeGroup NumVotesOnPost = new BadgeGroup() { Description = "Number of votes on a post" };
    BGs.Add(NumVotesOnPost);

foreach (BadgeGroup BG in BGs)
    db.BadgeGroups.AddOrUpdate(BG);
     db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you save a list of objects, EF doesn't guarantee that it'll be saved in that order. After you save, you can iterate through the objects to get their ids.

Comment: GRRR!, so ok.. I have to not have auto incrementing class.. :/